# Appending to a file, then reading from it into a list, then re-appending to it and overwriting certain parts

Tags: python

I want to be able to have a program whereby the user can input a paragraph/sentence/word/character whatever and have that stored in a list e.g. in list[0]. Then I want them to be able to write another bit of text and have that stored in e.g. list[1]. Then at any time I want the user to be able to read that from the list by choosing which segment they want to read from e.g. reading "hello" from list[0] whilst in list[1] "hi" is stored. Then when the user exits the program I want the list to be written to an external file. Then, at next start up, the program should read the file contents and store it again in the list so that the user can add more bits of text or read the current bits. When the list is saved to a file it should append new or changed parts but overwrite parts that are the same so as not to have duplicates. I have attempted this without much success. I am to be honest not sure if it is possible. I have browsed similar forums and have found that hasn't helped much so here it is.

My code so far:

```
    import os
    import time
    import csv

    global write_list
    global f1_contents
    write_list = []


    def write():
        os.system("cls")
        user_story = input("Enter your text: \n")
        write_list.append(user_story)


    def read():
        os.system("cls")
        user_select_needs = True
        while user_select_needs == True:
            user_select = input("Enter the list section to read from or type exit: \n")
            if user_select == "exit":
                user_select_needs = False
            try:
                int(user_select)
                select = user_select
                select = int(select)
                try:
                    print(write_list[select])
                    user_select_needs = False
                    enter = input("Press enter:")
                except:
                    print("There is not stored data on that section!")           
            except ValueError:
                print("That is not a valid section!")



    def exit():
        os.system("cls")
        max_num_needs = True
        while max_num_needs == True:
            set_max_num = input("Set the storage: \n")
            try:
                int(set_max_num)
                max_num = set_max_num
                max_num = int(max_num)
                max_num_needs = False
            except:
                print("It must be an integer!")
        for i in range(0, max_num):
        f = open("Saves.txt", "a")
        f.write(write_list[i])
        f.close()
        os._exit(1)


    def main():
        store_num_needs = True
        while store_num_needs == True:
            set_store_num = input("State the current storage amount: \n")
            try:
                int(set_store_num)
                store_num = set_store_num
                store_num = int(store_num)
                store_num_needs = False
            except:
                print("It must be an integer!")
        try:
            f1 = open("Saves.txt", "r")
            for i in range(0, store_num+1):
                i, = f1.split("#")
            f1.close()
        except:
            print("--------Loading-------")
            time.sleep(1)    
        while True:
            os.system("cls")
            user_choice = ""
            print("Main Menu" + "\n" + "---------")
            print("1) Write")
            print("2) Read")
            print("3) Exit")
            while user_choice not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
                user_choice = input("Pick 1, 2 or 3 \n")
            if user_choice == "1":
                write()
            elif user_choice == "2":
                read()
            else:
                exit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

It might be too complicated to understand in which case just ask me in comments- otherwise general tips would be nice aswell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have useless "int(xxx)" statements which do nothing... Your try/except statements are too general and may trap another error. Also, why do you import csv as it is not used? Unicity can be enforced by a set() but to preserve order, you must use the set only for testing, and keep the list for storing. But most important: What is it that you cannot make work? I think the read method with i, = f1.split("#") is strange...

Comment: Oh, I imported csv earlier because I tried something out using but then scrapped that bit of code and forgot to delete the import. What do you mean by unicity?

Comment: I cannot get it to do what I specified at the start of the question

Comment: I thought you wanted to preserve unicity. But maybe I just misunderstood. You just want to create some kind of line-by-line text editor I reckon. If the problem is: you cannot read what you saved, I wouldn't be surprised.Oh found another problem: you append each line in your save loop. You have do delete the save file at some point, or data keeps being appended to the old data.

Comment: The f1.split("#") is used as I decided that I would end all bits of text with a # and that would split the texts

Comment: You say I have used useless or too general parts of code- are you able to refine and correct what I have given because if so that would be great!

Comment: As a tip to make you code a bit more pythonic, you take a total of three lines to write to a file, which you could condense. Consider changing `f = open("Saves.txt", "a");

        f.write(write_list[i]);

        f.close()` into `with open("Saves.txt", "a") as f: f.write(write_list[i])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick point of correction:

`global` is only required if you're defining a global variable inside a non-global context. In other words, anything defined at the default indentation level, will be accessible by everything else defined below it. For example:

```
def set_global():
    x = 1

def use_global():
    x += 1

set_global()
try:
    use_global()
except Exception as e:
    # `use_global` doesn't know
    # about what `set_global` did
    print("ERROR: " + str(e))

# to resolve this we can set `x` to a
# default value in a global context:

x = 1

# or, if it were required, we
# could create a global variable

def make_global():
    global x
make_global()

# either will work fine

set_global()
use_global()
print(x) # prints 2
```

Now to the actual question:

I haven't read through the block of code you wrote (probably best to trim it down to just the relevant bits in the future), but this should solve the problem as I understand it, and you described it.

```
import os
import sys

user_text = []
# login the user somehow
user_file = 'saves.txt'

def writelines(f, lines):
    """Write lines to file with new line characters"""
    f.writelines('\n'.join(lines))

def readlines(f):
    """Get lines from file split on new line characters"""
    text = f.read()
    return text.split('\n') if text else []

class _Choice(object):
    """Class that is equivalent to a set of choices

    Example:

    >>> class YesObj(Choice):
    >>>     options = ('y', 'yes')
    >>> Yes = YesObj()
    >>> assert Yes == 'yes'
    >>> assert Yes == 'y'
    >>> # assertions evaluate to True

    Override the `options` attribute to make use
    """
    allowed = ()
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            s = str(other)
        except:
            raise TypeError("Cannot compare with non-string")
        else:
            return s.lower() in self.allowed

def _choice_repr(choices):
    allowed = []
    for c in choices:
        if isinstance(c, _Choice):
            allowed.extend(c.allowed)
        else:
            allowed.append(c)
    if len(allowed) > 2:
        s = ', '.join([repr(c) for c in allowed[:-1]])
        s += ', or %s' % repr(allowed[-1])
    elif len(allowed) == 1:
        s = '%s or %s' % allowed
    else:
        s = '%s' % allowed[0]
    return s

def _choice_sentinel(name, allowed):
    """Creates a sentinel for comparing options"""
    return type(name, (_Choice,), {'allowed': list(allowed)})()

Quit = _choice_sentinel('Quit', ('q', 'quit'))
Yes = _choice_sentinel('Yes', ('y', 'yes'))
No = _choice_sentinel('No', ('n', 'no'))


def readline_generator(f):
    """Generate a file's lines one at a time"""
    t = f.readline()
    # while the line isn't empty
    while bool(t):
        yield t
        t = f.readline()

def read_from_cache():
    """Overwrite `user_text` with file content"""
    if not os.path.isfile(user_file):
        open(user_file, 'w').close()
        globals()['user_text'] = []
    else:
        with open(user_file, 'r') as f:
            lines = readlines(f)
            # replace vs extend user text
            for i, t in enumerate(lines):
                if i == len(user_text):
                    user_text.extend(lines[i:])
                else:
                    user_text[i] = t

def write_to_cache():
    """Overwrite cache after the first line disagrees with current text

    If modifications have been made near the end of the file, this will
    be more efficient than a blindly overwriting the cache."""
    with open(user_file, 'r+') as f:
        i = -1
        last_pos = f.tell()
        # enumerate is a generator, not complete list
        for i, t in enumerate(readline_generator(f)):
            if user_text[i] != t:
                # rewind to the line before
                # this diff was encountered
                f.seek(last_pos)
                # set the index back one in
                # order to catch the change
                i -= 1
                break
            last_pos = f.tell()

        # then cut off remainder of file
        f.truncate()

        # recall that i is the index of the diff

        # replace the rest of it with new
        # (and potentially old) content
        writelines(f, user_text[i+1:])

def blind_write_to_cache():
    """Blindly overwrite the cache with current text"""
    with open(user_file, 'w') as f:
        writelines(f, user_text)

def overwrite_user_text(i, text, save=False):
    """Overwrite a line of text

    If `save` is True, then these changes are cached
    """
    try:
        user_text[i] = text
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError("No text exists on line %r" % (i+1))
    if save:
        write_to_cache()

def user_input():
    """Get a new line from the user"""
    return raw_input("input text: ")

def user_choice(msg, choices):
    if len(choices) == 0:
        raise ValueError("No choices were given")
    ans = raw_input(msg)
    if ans not in choices:
        print("Invalid Response: '%s'" % ans)
        m = "Respond with %s: " % _choice_repr(choices)
        return user_choice(m, choices)
    else:
        return ans

def user_appends():
    """User adds a new line"""
    user_text.append(user_input())

def user_reads(*args, **kwargs):
    """Print a set of lines for the user

    Selects text via `user_text[slice(*args)]`
    Use 'print_init' in kwargs to choose how
    many lines are printed out before user must
    scroll by pressing enter, or quit with 'q'."""
    print_init = kwargs.get('print_init', 4)
    sliced = user_text[slice(*args)]
    if not isinstance(sliced, list):
        sliced = [sliced]
    for i, l in enumerate(sliced):
        if i < print_init:
            print(l)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        elif user_choice(l, ['', Quit]) == Quit:
            break

def user_changes(i=None, save=False):
    """User changes a preexisting line"""
    attempt = True
    while i is None and attempt:
        # get the line the user wants to change
        i_text = raw_input("Line to be changed: ")
        try:
            # make user input an index
            i = int(i_text)
        except:
            # check if they want to try again
            c = user_choice("Bad input - '%s' is not an "
                "integer. Try again? " % i_text, (Yes, No))
            attempt = (c == Yes)
    if attempt:
        # user gave a valid integer for indexing
        try:
            user_reads(i-1)
            overwrite_user_text(i-1, user_input(), save)
        except Exception as e:
            print("ERROR: %s" % e)
            if user_choice("Try again? ", (Yes, No)):
                user_changes(i, save)


# stores whatever text is already on
# file to `user_text` before use
read_from_cache()
```

Comment: @Matt Python is an object oriented language ([more info](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)) and I took advantage of what it has to off, but really all I'm doing is making [sentinels](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) that are equal to both "y" and "yes" or "n" and "no". However note that "sentinel" is simply a term, not a built in part of Python. So that shouldn't really hinder your ability to read the rest of the code. Let me know if you have more questions and I can help direct you to the relevant resources.

Comment: Okay, the code seems to be good but I do not know what I should put for the login section. The code will not work if I do not have a value for login_file() and the question is now how do I get one?

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention is here. If there's only ever going to be one user, you can just set `user_file = '<whatever_file_you_want>'`. If you need help setting up a system for more than one user, that's a subject for another question. However, if you feel that I've answered what you've asked here, you should upvote, and select this as the correct answer.

Comment: This line: return type(name, (_StringEnum,), {'options', list(options)})()
returns a type error "Unhashable list"

Comment: typo, should be: `type(name, (_StringEnum,), {'options': list(options)})()`

Comment: Another error comes up on this line: No = _options_sentinel('No', 'n', 'no') _options_sentinel() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Use the same format as the line above, there are missing `()`

Comment: What does this code actually do tho because now if I run it only press any key to continue comes up

Comment: Ok, everything is fixed. There was a subtle bug with indexing. Now as for what this does, nothing now, however all the tools are there to make it do something. Calling `user_appends()` will prompt the user for a new line `write_to_cache()` will save that line, and `user_changes()` prompts the user to change a pre-existing line.

Comment: still another error :) 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment' on this line: globals['user_text'] = []

Comment: should be `globals()` not `globals`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114971/discussion-between-whiskeyandrye-and-matt).